# How can I Number format items in PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, numbers, format, number-formatting

I have a 2-column table with a description and a number.  The descriptions and numbers are called as $POST values and stored in an array.  The array values are then used to send the data table in an email message.

I need to re-format each number in the array as currency ($X.XX).  I can't get number_format to work properly when applied to numbers in the array.

$stringVals[0] = description

$stringVals[1] = number I want to format

Without number formatting:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value){
        if (substr($key, 0, 5) == "rowE-")
        {
            $tmp = str_replace('"', "", substr($value, 1, strlen($value) - 2));
            $stringVals = explode(",", $tmp);
            $messageBody .= "<tr><td><strong>";
            $messageBody .= $stringVals[0];
            $messageBody .= ":</strong>&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;</td><td>";
            $messageBody .= $stringVals[1];
            $messageBody .= "</td><tr>";
        }
    }
```

I tried the below in context of the above, but without success:

```
$tmpString .= $stringVals[1];
$messageBody .= number_format($tmpString, 2,',', '.');;
```

Comment: Why are you _appending_ to `$tmpString` here? Why a temp variable in the first place? What does `$stringVals[1]` actually contain at this point?

Comment: And why do you have to fish description and “number” out of _one_ POST value to begin with, why are those not send as separate values in the first place?

Comment: @04FS `$tmpString` was probably my very bad attempt at getting a single variable out of the array.  `$stringVals[1]` contains a number each time the loop runs.  I don't understand why  `number_format($stringVals[0], 2,',', '.');` doesn't work since the variable value is a number each pass through the loop. The reason for the fish relates to how I needed to stringify the data before posting it to the email php file.

Answer (score -2):

```
$tmpString .= $stringVals[1];
$messageBody .= number_format($tmpString, 2,',', '.');;
```

Your second line code use two semicolon. Try remove one.

Comment: Thanks @Reks.  Bad copy paste.  The extra semi wasn't actually in the code.